# FlashDevelop - Cannot Target Flash

Tags: flash, target, flashdevelop

I've just recently installed FlashDevelop, OpenFL etc - so this is all really new to me.

Wrote a very basic Haxe / OpenFL program and it works fine when I use HTML5 or Windows as the target platform.  When I select Flash for the target I get 'Catastrophic failure'.

I've checked Tools -> Install Software and ticked runtimes for 'Adobe Air', Flash Player (SA) and under Compilers 'Flesk and AIR SDK'.  'Adobe Air' was already installed but an old version so that was updated, 'flash Player (SA) doesn't seem to have been installed, so that is no installed and it downloaded and extracted the 'Flesk & AIR SDK'.  Unfortunately - still no joy. So, if anyon has any other suggestions - be more than welcome.  (Also deinstalled and reinstalled but no joy).

Am I right in saying that I need Flash in order to be able to Debug?

Any suggestions very much welcomed

Oliver

[image: Point where compile / build failed]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Haxe (I code in pure AS3), but out of FD output I can say the build was successful, yet the run wasn't. Do you have Flash Player runtime also installed? Flex and/or AIR SDK as suggested here: http://haxe3.blogspot.ru/2013/07/setting-up-flashdevelop-for-haxe-3-and.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for that suggestion - had a good read of the article and went back to do some changes which I've noted in my original post - unfortunately still no joy.  Do you know if it is possible to debug without creating the flash option?

Comment: First, you can try to open the compiled SWF in StandAlone Flash Player, just to see if it works. Then you can (probably) try to set up a custom playback instead of whatever default things Haxe and OpenFL have there.

Comment: Ho Organis - that seems to be the problem (presuming I've found the right 'swf' file) - it doesn't run.  Is the output stored in 'Project Directory/bin/flash/release/bin'?  If so, when I double Click it starts a program that just gives info about the Flash file - it has a reference to  'MediaInfo.net/MediaInfo.  Looks like some reference to Flash Player and/or Flash Player is missing.

Comment: OK - turns out that it is not linking to Flash Player - instead, the association for .swf was to something called MediaInfo.  I can't find the Standalone Flash Player anywhere on computer even though Stencyl manages to run it when I develop games on that platform.  I found a program called MPC-HC and it runs it OK so immediate problem over.

Comment: Anyone any idea where / how to install the official standalone Flash Player or how to find it ( as I'm fairly certain it is already installed)?  Thanks

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for that link.  I must be doing something really basic wrong.  When I use that link it brings me to the usual downloader and I end up with a chrome installation.  I did find on some forum - unfortunately cannot remember where a zip file of adobe flash players and it included a flashplayer12_0r0_38_win_sa_debug which seems to be working.  Am wondering if Adobe distribute stand alone versions anymore because the only one I can find on their website is for Linux?

Comment: Pretty weird, because there are all kinds of player builds (browser plugins and standalones) for all relevant systems. I always get there by google > debug flash player download.

Comment: weird is right.  Must be some setting on my computer that's screwing everything up.  Anyway, I have the 'old flash Player 12 Debug' and it seems to be coping OK with output from Debug flashDevelop - so happy days.  Thanks for help and pointers - much appreciated.  Oliver